# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list - How do I convert a list into a text file to be stored?

Tags: python

```
houses = [] 
#print(houses)
#Creates an empty list for the houses

f = open("houses.txt", "r+")
#Creates a variable called "f" which opens the houses.txt file and imports it r+ = Read and + means you can append on the end
lines = f.readlines()
#The readlines() method returns a list containing each line in the file as a list item. Use the hint parameter to limit the number of lines returned.

#The for loop grabs each line of text from the file, and splits the houses and scores and makes them separate. It runs for as many lines are in the text file
for line in lines:
  #The append adds the stripped and split code separately in a list
  #.strip .split separates the houses and scores into separate strings
  houses.append(line.strip().split())
for i in range(len(houses)):
  #Loops for how many houses are in the list
  houses[i][1] = int(houses[i][1])
  #Turns the second part of the list into an integer

print(houses)
```

This part of the code imports houses (teams) from the text file which is laid out like this:

```
StTeresa 0
StKolbe 0
StMary 0
StAnn 0
```

I created a function to save the points. I would basically like it to take the houses and scores from the list in the program. To do so, it will delete all the contents in the text file, and then I would like it to rewrite it in the same format as the original text file to keep the updated house scores.

```
def save():
  f.truncate(0)
  f.write(str(houses))
```

I tried this but the output is:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSmRD.png)

Can anyone help me to rewrite the text file to include the updated scores and be in the same format as the text file orignally was?

Comment: Use the `csv` module, then you can use `writerows(houses)`

Comment: Hey, I did what you said and I received another error. 

  File "main.py", line 149, in save
    f.writerows(houses)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerows'

Comment: Then you didn't use the `csv` module correctly. That's a methos of the `csv.writer` object, not the `file`.

Comment: I have sorted out the CSV module and it will now export into the text file again.
`def save():
  f.truncate(0)
  with open('houses.txt', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([houses])`
However how do I remove the [] and separate each item in the list as it was laid out before. As of now it exports as:
`"[['StAnn', 0], ['StMary', 20], ['StKolbe', 0], ['StTeresa', 0]]"`

Back into the text file. How would I export it to be formatted like before which was: 

`StTeresa 0
StKolbe 0
StMary 0
StAnn 0`

It can all be string.

Comment: `writerow(houses)`. It's already a list, you don't have to put `[]` around it.

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you want:

```
def save():
    with open("houses.txt", "w") as file:
        for index, line_content in enumerate(houses):
            houses[index][1] = str(houses[index][1])
        file.write("\n".join(map(lambda sub_list: " ".join(sub_list), houses)))
```

However, as you can see, this is quite hacky.
So I would have two main recommendations for your code:

1. Use `open()` within a `with` statement. Currently your code does not reliably close the file it opens, which can cause your code to do unexpected things (for example when an exception is thrown in the middle of your processing). Therefore, it is recommended practice to use `with` (further information on this can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files))
2. Instead of using lists within a list, you could use tuples:

   ```
    for line in lines:
        # The append adds the stripped and split code separately in a list
        # .strip .split separates the houses and scores into separate strings
        house_name, house_score = tuple(line.strip().split())
        houses.append((house_name, int(house_score)))
   ```

   This gives you something like this: `[("StTeresa", 0), ("StKolbe", 0), ("StMary", 0), ("StAnn", 0)]`. Tuples in lists have the advantage that you can unpack them in loops, which makes it easier to handle them compared to a list within a list:

   for index, (house_name, house_score) in enumerate(houses):
   # do something with the score
   houses[index] = (house_name, updated_score)

Another option is to follow what Barmar suggested and use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=open%20file#module-csv), which is part of the standard library.

As a bonus: `enumerate()` provides you the indices of an iterable, so you can easily loop over them. So instead of

```
for i in range(len(houses)):
    #Loops for how many houses are in the list
```

you can write

```
for i, house in enumerate(houses):
    # Loop over all the houses
```

which makes the code a little easier to read and write.

So with all my suggestions combined you could have a `save()` function like this:

```
def save():
    with open("houses.txt", "w") as file:
        for house_name, house_score in houses:
            file.write(f"{house_name} {house_score}\n")
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! That was the last piece of the puzzle for the program to work! It now updates the text file and imports it again to be used to add more points! Thank you for the extra tips too, I will look into them :)

Comment: I just have another thing I am confused about, is that every time the program runs, say if I want to add 20 points to a house, it will do it. But the second time I run the program and want to add 20 points instead it will add 40, then 60 etc. Could you look at this?

Comment: `houseChoice = int(input("\nWhat house are you adding points to? (0-3): "))
    if houseChoice > -1 and houseChoice < 4:
      acaPlace = int(input("\nWhat place did they finish in? "))
      #houses = [["House1"], 0] , ["House2", 0]]
      if acaPlace == 1:
        print("\nThey received 20 points!")
        houses[houseChoice][1] = int(houses[0][1]) + 20
        print(houses)
        save()`

I don't know why it happens!

Comment: I think this is because you have a hard coded 0 index in your calculation `houses[houseChoice][1] = int(houses[0][1]) + 20`. Instead, you probably want `houses[houseChoice][1] = int(houses[houseChoice][1]) + 20`

Comment: Thank you again! The program works fully now! I appreciate all the help :)